# getting error TypeError: Member "transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Hi I need one help as I am unable to run below logic in solidity as some change in solidity.

```
function transfer_balance(address recipient_address, uint amount) 
public returns(bool) {
    if(msg.sender == owner){
         if (amount <= get_balance()){
             //transfer the amount received as argument to the recipient_address
             recipient_address.transfer(amount);<-- error here
             return true;
         }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Error is

> TypeError: Member "transfer" not found or not visible after argument- 
>   dependent lookup in address.
>                    recipient_address.transfer(amount);
>                    ^------------------------^

This is little confusing as it was run  on old version on solidity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number [breaking changes](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/050-breaking-changes.html) when moving from Solidity version 0.4.X to 0.5.X

One of the big differences is the introduction of the `address payable` type, which is different than `address`. Only a variable with the `address payable` type has the `transfer` function:

> The `address` type was split into `address` and `address payable`, where
>   only `address payable` provides the `transfer` function. An `address payable` can be directly converted to an `address`, but the other way
>   around is not allowed. Converting `address` to `address payable` is
>   possible via conversion through `uint160`. If `c` is a contract,
>   `address(c)` results in `address payable` only if `c` has a payable fallback
>   function. If you use the [withdraw pattern](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common-patterns.html#withdrawal-pattern), you most likely do not have
>   to change your code because `transfer` is only used on `msg.sender`
>   instead of stored addresses and `msg.sender` is an `address payable`.

So the simple solution here is to update you function definition to:

```
function transfer_balance(address payable recipient_address, uint amount) public returns(bool)
```

Comment: Thanks@shawn its work. I have check the breaking changes in solidity and reform my code accroding to it.